# Pass a variable between the screens React-Native when using RadioButton

Tags: parameter-passing, react-native

I have created a sort of form and I want to pass a variable to the next screen when press submit.

```
var states = [
  {label: "happy", value: 1},
  {label: "sad", value: 2},
  {label: "angry", value: 3},
  {label: "relaxed", value: 4}
];

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Paragraph style={styles.textStyle}>How are you feeling today ?</Paragraph>
        <RadioForm
          radio_props={states}
          initial={2}
          onPress={(value) => {ToastAndroid.show(value.toString(), ToastAndroid.SHORT)}}
          buttonSize={30}
          buttonOuterSize={40}
          selectedButtonColor={'blue'}
          selectedLabelColor={'blue'}
          labelStyle={{ fontSize: 15, }}
          disabled={false}
          formHorizontal={false}
          />
       
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ButtonsScreen')}/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

So, I want to pass variable "value" ( which the user selects ) to the 'ButtonsScreen'.
Anyone has any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  
  state = { val: "" }; // set state here

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        ....
        <RadioForm
          ....
          onPress={(value) => {
            this.setState({ val: value });
          }}
          ....
        />

        <Button
          title="Submit"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate("ButtonsScreen", {
              value: this.state.val,
            })
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives the error: " Can't find variable "value" ".